# Cisco Flexvpn Dvti Setup not working any more if Spoke site is behind NAT

Tags: cisco, ikev2

I have set up a platform (consisting of 2x ASR1001X) routers as Flexvpn DVTI hubs to terminate different remote sites (mostly ISR1000, but also older C886s) into different VRFs.
The authorization backend is a Freeradius.

Enclosed my Hub Config

```
crypto ikev2 name-mangler MANGLER-1
 email all
!
crypto ikev2 profile FLEX-BOX-1
 match identity remote address ::/0
 match identity remote address 0.0.0.0 
 match identity remote email domain *****.com
 identity local fqdn hub1.****.com
 authentication remote pre-share
 authentication local rsa-sig
 keyring aaa NTVPN name-mangler MANGLER-1 password cisco
 pki trustpoint TP-1
 dpd 60 10 periodic
 aaa authorization user psk list VPN name-mangler MANGLER-1 password cisco
 virtual-template 800
!
crypto ipsec transform-set AES_128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
 mode tunnel
crypto ipsec transform-set AES_128-SHA_256 esp-aes esp-sha256-hmac 
 mode tunnel
crypto ipsec transform-set AES_256-SHA esp-aes 256 esp-sha-hmac 
 mode tunnel
crypto ipsec transform-set AES_256-SHA_256 esp-aes 256 esp-sha256-hmac 
 mode tunnel
!
crypto ipsec profile IPSEC-1
 set security-association lifetime seconds 7200
 set transform-set AES_256-SHA_256 AES_256-SHA AES_128-SHA_256 AES_128-SHA 
 set pfs group15
 set ikev2-profile FLEX-BOX-1
 responder-only
!
interface Virtual-Template800 type tunnel
 ip unnumbered Loopback800
 no ip redirects
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip mtu 1400
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1300
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 tunnel protection ipsec profile IPSEC-NTVPN-1
```

and the Spoke site:

```
crypto ikev2 client flexvpn default
  peer 1 *****
  no backup group
  client connect Tunnel1
!
crypto ikev2 authorization policy default
 no route set interface
 route set remote ipv4 10.240.1.32 255.255.255.255
!
!
crypto ikev2 profile Flex_IKEv2
 match identity remote fqdn domain ***.com
 identity local email ***@***.com
 authentication remote rsa-sig
 authentication local pre-share key *****
 pki trustpoint TP-VPN
 dpd 60 10 periodic
 aaa authorization user cert list default default
!
crypto ipsec profile default
 set ikev2-profile Flex_IKEv2
!
! 
! 
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip address negotiated
 ip mtu 1400
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1300
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 tunnel destination dynamic
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 tunnel protection ipsec profile default
```

i excluded the whole PKI/AAA/RADIUS stuff because the plain authentication is working fine.

The story works fine as long as the spoke site has a public IP address on the internet. But as soon as the device is behind a NAT I can't get a tunnel anymore.

The hub router logs following *hints*

```
Mar 10 15:59:36.976: IKEv2-ERROR:: A supplied parameter is incorrect
Mar 10 15:59:37.692: IKEv2-ERROR:Couldn't find matching SA: Detected an invalid IKE SPI 

Mar 10 15:59:50.443: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Virtual-Access4, changed state to down
Mar 10 15:59:50.455: IKEv2:% DVTI Vi4 created for profile FLEX-BOX-1 with PSH index 2.

Mar 10 15:59:50.455: IKEv2:IPSec policy validate request sent for profile FLEX-BOX-1 with psh index 2.

Mar 10 15:59:50.456: IKEv2:(SA ID = 2):[IPsec -> IKEv2] Callback received for the validate proposal - FAILED.
```

as soon as i turn back to a WAN access where the Spoke-Side Router has an non-NAT globally reachable address everything works fine again.

any ideas what this could be or how to isolate the root-cause of my problem?

Comment: I have done some research and I think the problem is that I have not defined SA on the hub router.
I have the "Remote Network" transmitted from the spoke site and accept it via the RADIUS attribute: "Cisco-AVPair = ipsec:route-set=interface". 
The routing on the spoke router itself is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it...

after monitoring some Packets and noticed a lot of retransmissions we solved the issue by setting

`crypto ikev2 fragmentation`